# How can I display a string which excess 254 chars in Crystal Reports 8.5?

Tags: string, string-length, crystal-reports-8.5

hi 
How can I display a string which excess 254 chars in my report created by crystal reports 8.5?
My application that shows the report ia a vb6.0 application.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have to build it up in CR 8.5.
[Check out this example.](http://www.crystalkeen.com/articles/crystalreports/string254.htm)

If using a database, you would have to split the string into several columns before it gets passed into crystal.

Answer (score 0):

Use Memo datatype in the report definition instead of the String.